# Склонение слов в зависимости от числительных в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравтвуйте, есть вот такой скрипт, который при открытии страницы в блоке `div` добавляет слово с правильным склонением к возрасту (22 года).

```
<div class="age-count" id="one">22</div>

var count = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;

function declination(number, titles) {
cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
return titles[ (number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2:cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5] ];
}
title = declination(count, [' год', ' года', ' лет']);
var age = count + title;
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = age;
```

Подскажите, как мне сделать тоже самое только без `id`,-  прогнать несколько значений сразу. Например,- если у меня будут сразу 5-ть `div` с классом `age-count`, которые будут проходить через функцию при открытии страницы.

Я пробовал сделать с помощью цикла и Document.getElementsByClassName() но что-то не получается у меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll`,- чтобы получить все элементы и `forEach`,- чтобы перебрать их.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.age-count')

elements.forEach(function (el) {
  const count = el.textContent
  const title = declination(count, [' год', ' года', ' лет'])
  const age = count + title
  
  el.textContent = age
})

function declination(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[ (number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2:cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5] ];
}
```

```html
<div class="age-count">22</div>
<div class="age-count">5</div>
<div class="age-count">17</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.