# Пишу программу которая показывает время в консоли, как склонять время?(минута, минут, минуты итд) javascript

Tags: javascript

Я так понял что прописывать нужно через массив, а как именно не понимаю.

Comment: Гуглить не пробовал? https://itchief.ru/javascript/working-with-date-and-time && https://realadmin.ru/coding/sklonenie-na-javascript.html

Comment: Есть ещё библиотека https://date-fns.org/

Comment: [js склонение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5): [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708558/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975916/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/887912/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
function numstr(n, text_forms) {  
    var m = Math.abs(n) % 100; 
    var n1 = m % 10;
    if (m > 10 && m < 20) { return text_forms[2]; }
    if (n1 > 1 && n1 < 5) { return text_forms[1]; }
    if (n1 == 1) { return text_forms[0]; }
    return text_forms[2];
}

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var minutes = 10; //меняем значение

var result = `${minutes} ${numstr(minutes, ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут'])}`;

container.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: ...спасибо...

Comment: @НикитаНармонтас если помог, можете принять мой ответ =) Удачи в разработке ваших проектов!